# Find the beginning and ending of consecutive numbers in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have an input list:

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11]
```

And I am trying to get the following as output:

```
lows = [1, 5, 9]
highs = [3, 6, 11]
```

The `lows` list contains all the lowest numbers of all the sublists of consecutive numbers in the list:  `[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], and [9, 10, 11]`. The highs, vice versa.

- A sublist is guaranteed to have at least 2 members.
- All numbers in the input list will be unique.

What's the cleanest way to accomplish this? I'm wondering if there is something in `itertools` that could do this nicely?

Comment: Can you instead put answers in answers, please?

Comment: I'll just remove mine and accept yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always the obvious manual method:

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11]

def runs(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    start = end = next(iterator)

    for item in iterator:
        if item != end + 1:
            yield (start, end)
            start = item

        end = item

    yield (start, end)

lows, highs = zip(*runs(s))

lows
#>>> (1, 5, 9)

highs
#>>> (3, 6, 11)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, count
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> s = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11]
>>> ig = itemgetter(0, -1)
>>> lows, highs = zip(*(ig(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(s, lambda x, c=count(): x-next(c))))
>>> lows
(1, 5, 9)
>>> highs
(3, 6, 11)
```

Comment: I already accepted Veedrac's answer, but thanks for another approach.